# How to load a html page in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, client-side

I am trying to load a website into JavaScript so I can scrape it. My question is how would i load the website into client side JavaScript? I have tried loading it into a iframe and a JavaScript object element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use AJAX. In most cases, though, the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will trip you up - JavaScript on `example.com` can't access the source code of `example.net` because they're different domains.

If both sites are under your control, [CORS can fix this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). If you're trying to scrape something like Facebook, you'd have to proxy the requests with some sort of server-side language like PHP.